# What is the use of Async Mode methods in CompletableFuture when next stage will only start after finishing previous stage?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> future = supplyAsync(()-> 4);

future.thenApplyAsync(data -> doSomeHeavyTask()   
      .thenApplyAsync(data -> doSomeLiteTask())
      .thenAccept(System.out::println);
```

here we know for sure that main thread will do its own task if it has something to do so main is in async mode..
but doSomeLiteTask() will only start after finishing doSomeHeavyTask() so why async ?

Comment: As you said, “so main is in async mode”. In other words, neither `doSomeHeavyTask()` nor `doSomeLiteTask()` will be executed in the main thread. So what’s your question?

Comment: yes i get it thanks..i was just confused that why they provided async version of almost every method..let say your previous completionStage is done by commons' pool thread then next stage will be done by may be main thread if main thread has nothing to do or may be by   same commons' pool thread that completes previous stage if the operation is blocking so main thread will not be blocked..am i Correct?  and instead of providing so many overloaded async versions they could have provided a single async() method so whole pipeline is either sync or async as Streams api has parallel mode..

Comment: The streams have a pipeline that can be configured to be parallel or sequential. The futures do not. Each time, you call `then…` on a future, you are creating a new future and set up an action to be done when the first futures completes, to attempt to complete the other. Not only are all four futures of your question’s example independent, they have no coupling to the completion attempts you set up. You could call `complete` with a value on any of them, making pending asynchronous completion attempts ineffective.

Comment: got it..thanks and completableFuture is little bit similar to what javascript has Promises